# Divide the value of each row by the SUM of this column

Tags: sql, algorithm, ms-access

I have a query that display items with name and its weight with respect to the entire bucket of items. These buckets are sub-categorized so I want to convert total weight to sub-category weight.

Pre-adjustment, with weight with respect to entire bucket looks as follows.

```
InvestmentName  Weight
Ac              0.01236194
AG              0.04102656
Ca              0.02483226
DF              0.02951128
Ea              0.003295817
GE              0.005415929
```

This is the desired result I quickly did in Excel, which I could not achieve with a query right now. The numbers sum to 1 as desired:

```
InvestmentName  AdjWeight
Ac              0.106162299
AG              0.352329321
Ca              0.213255347
DF              0.253437998
Ea              0.028303932
GE              0.046511104
```

Basically the task here is to divide each entry by the `SUM` of the all the weights in the first table above.

I tried:

```
SELECT InvestmentName, Weight / SUM(Weight) AS AdjWeight FROM Records WHERE = "..."
```

and Access said can't divide entries by aggregate. Is there a way to store the SUM(Weight) as a variable somewhere from a query and use it on each individual weight?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`SELECT InvestmentName, Weight / (SELECT SUM(Weight) FROM Records) AS AdjWeight FROM Records;`

Comment: Why can't you do that using partition by or simply using sum(weight)?